# The project ‘Pods’ is damaged and cannot be opened. Examine the project file for invalid edits or unresolved source control conflicts

Tags: xcode

My "pods" after pod install are not recognised by Xcode and cause my build to failed.

This is the message I have while trying to opening pods from *Pods/Pods.xcodeproj*:

**The project ‘Pods’ is damaged and cannot be opened. Examine the project file for invalid edits or unresolved source control conflicts.**

This is my podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false


target 'applicationTemplate' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  # Pods for applicationTemplate
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  pod 'RNFBAnalytics', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics'
  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
  pod 'react-native-voice', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-voice'
  pod 'react-native-torch', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-torch'
  pod 'RNKeychain', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-keychain'
  
  pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  pod 'RNOpenAppSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-app-settings'

  target 'applicationTemplateTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'applicationTemplate-tvOS' do
  # Pods for applicationTemplate-tvOS

  target 'applicationTemplate-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

# App Tracking Transparency https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#disable-ad-id-usage-on-ios
$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-config'
      phase = target.project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXShellScriptBuildPhase)
      phase.shell_script = "cd ../../"\
      " && RNC_ROOT=./node_modules/react-native-config/"\
      " && export SYMROOT=$RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig"\
      " && ruby $RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig/BuildDotenvConfig.ruby"
      
      target.build_phases << phase
      target.build_phases.move(phase,0)
    end
  end
  react_native_post_install(installer)
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue:

Just removing this line: `install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false` and run `pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all && pod install`

I added it because I was using react-native upgrade helper and I saw that in their podfile their was this line so I added it but apparently it does not work for every upgrade so be careful with upgrade helper.